# How can I add additional attributes to nested array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add in additional key/value pairs to a nested array before passing it to CJSON::encode()?

```
    public static function WS_getAllComments($topic_id){
    $model = ExploreComment::model()->with('user')->findAll(array("condition" => "topic_id = '" . $topic_id . "'"));

    $json = CJSON::encode($model);

    return $json;
}
```

The above code returns me a nested array which looks like this

```
[{"comment_id":"1","user_id":"1","topic_id":"1","data":"This will be my first test comment with 5 stars","image_append":null,"rating":"5","datetime":"2014-08-15 14:36:42"},
{"comment_id":"2","user_id":"2","topic_id":"1","data":"This is another comment with dummy user","image_append":null,"rating":"3","datetime":"2014-08-15 18:00:17"}]
```

What I intended to do is to add few more attributes which queried from the relative AR and add it into the list like such:

```
[{blablabla, "NewKey":"NewValue"},{blablabla, "NewKey":"NewValue"}]
```

so that finally when I encode my JSON data the new key/value pairs will be in its appropriate locations...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to tackle this, what are your thoughts on how to do this? It's always good to tell us what you've tried before asking a question. You're going to have to transform your $model into a new type to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Convert json to array

$newElement = json_decode('[{"NewKey":"NewValue"},{"NewKey":"NewValue"}]' , true);

//merge array to $model array

$resultArray = array_merge($model, $newElement);

//convert to json
$json = json_encode($model);

return $json;
```